# Use toolbar without using extends AppCompactActivity

Tags: android, toolbar, appcompatactivity

i have using a toolbar that needs AppCompatActivity class and before it i used a FragmentActivity so i cant extends AppCompatActivity too

what is the solution to use setSupportActinBar that inherit from AppCompatActivity

this my code

```
public class currentActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{


private Toolbar mToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.current);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ctoolbar);

    //setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); //problem is here 
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);




    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    intialiseViewPager();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }

}
```

Comment: "before it i used a FragmentActivity so i cant extends AppCompatActivity too" -- `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: so how to use setSupportActionBar in my code  ????

Comment: Change `currentActivity` to extend `AppCompatActivity`. That is the only class that has `setSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: i didnt know this....so thanks a lot